# Add Initial Screen to Master/Detail app

Tags: android, android-studio, master-detail

I'm using Master/Detail example provided by Android Studio 1.5 and NavigationDrawer.

Everything works great, but in Tablet mode always I get two screen when I launch the app (is the normal operation)

Following the strategy in MainActivity to detect widths > 900 I can't see how to launch a Fragment that show in all the screen, just for the first time.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain the existing strategy that's provided, just add a hook to your master fragment for when an item is selected (which you probably want to do anyway so you can highlight the selected item).

Then, within the fragment, if there's no item currently selected, load a different layout that takes up the entire view.